# Prevent remounting of layout component if react router params stay the same

Tags: reactjs, optimization, react-router

I have a layout component which renders an image of quite a large size. This layout component is shared between two other components, Map and Explore. When the route changes, it renders either the Map or the Explore component, with the layout component wrapped around it.

A user gets to Map or Explore via the home page. So the link to the page could be '.../map/123' or '.../explore/456'. When switching between map and explore once the user is in the map or explore component, the url params remain the same always. So '.../map/123' or '.../explore/123'

On each route change, the layout component and the map/explore component is re-rendered. The problem is that the large image on the layout component is then re-fetched.

How should I structure the app so I can swtich from Map and Explore without having to refetch the large image?

I have the code in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6w6z11x24n)...

```js
//index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import Map from "./Map";
import Explore from "./Explore";

const Links = props => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <NavLink exact to="/">
        Home
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink style={{ paddingLeft: "5px" }} to="/map/1">
        Map
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink style={{ paddingLeft: "5px" }} to="/explore/1">
        Explore
      </NavLink>
    </nav>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Links />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <h1>Home</h1>} />
        <Route path="/map/:id" render={({ match }) => <Map match={match} />} />
        <Route
          path="/explore/:id"
          render={({ match }) => <Explore match={match} />}
        />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```js
//layout MapExploreContainer.js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class MapExploreContainer extends Component {
  state = { imgUrl: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        imgUrl:
          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550396011-0d98206d5b92?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjU1Nzk4fQ"
      });
    }, 2000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timeout);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("hi: ", this.props.match);
    return (
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
        <img src={this.state.imgUrl} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MapExploreContainer;
```

```js
//Map.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MapExploreContainter from "./MapExploreContainer";

class Map extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapExploreContainter match={this.props.match}>
        <div>Map</div>
      </MapExploreContainter>
    );
  }
}

export default Map;
```

```js
//Explore.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MapExploreContainter from "./MapExploreContainer";

class Explore extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapExploreContainter match={this.props.match}>
        <div>Explore</div>
      </MapExploreContainter>
    );
  }
}

export default Explore;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `Explore` and `Map` each get their own instance of `MapExploreContainer` which is unmounted when each of those components is unmounted.

You can try something like the following:

Remove all references to `MapExploreContainter` from `Map` and `Explore`

Change your routes to:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Links />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <h1>Home</h1>} />
        <Route path="/(map|explore)/:id" component={MapExploreContainter} />
        <Route path="/map/:id" render={({ match }) => <Map match={match} />} />
        <Route
          path="/explore/:id"
          render={({ match }) => <Explore match={match} />}
        />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This way the rendered `MapExploreContainer` is always the same instance whenever you're at either `map/123` or `explore/123`.

Updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/14xj47667j

Comment: Right, and depending on the url, either render the Map or the Explore component... ?

Comment: if you type e.g. `/map/123` the router will match `/map/:id` but also `(map|explore)/:id` because the router uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) you can use regex to match routes. When you navigate to `/explore/:123` it will unmount map and mount explore but not the container because is it still matching the route.